# Conditional selection of a cell below in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am running through all the cells in my table using this bit of code:

```
 df.loc[(df["month"]=="january"),"a5"]=1
```

Which assigns the value "1" in the a5 column for all the rows where the value in the month column is "january". I wanted to know if there was a way to assign "1" not to that row but to the row below.

I have tried to simply do

```
df.loc[(df["month"]=="january")+1,"a5"]=1
```

but it doesn't work. For some reason that I don't quite grasp, :

```
df.loc[(df["month"]=="january")+2,"a5"]=1
```

assigns 1 to the row that says "january" and to the row below.

Comment: are you using datatable or a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I'm using panda

Comment: you might wanna look at what `df["month"]=="january"` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'month':['j','k','j','k'],'a5':[10,10,10,10]})

index = (df["month"]=="j").shift(1) # shift by 1 after shifting first value will be nan so we need to fill that with False
index[0] = False # 

df.loc[index,'a5']=1 
print(df)
>>>  
   month  a5
0     j   10
1     k    1
2     j   10
3     k    1
```

- When you write some query liek this `df['somthing'] = x`. It will return Series contain `True` if condition meets, `False` otherwise.
- Idea here is to shift all values down by one and `False` in start.
- I hope this clarify few thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(df["month"]=="january"),"a5"]=1
```

And then just use shift to move it to the next row:

```
df["a5"].shift(1)
```

Should work.

Comment: It will fill `nan` in the first row. And last row will be lost.

Comment: You are right, but if I have understood the question correctly, it should not be an issue.

Comment: You are losing last row of the data. Which should not be the case. Check my answer which preserve all data and also takes care of nan value added by shift command.

Comment: Poojan not loosing any data as far as I can see. I am only shifting the column where value is being assigned. Assumption being this is a new column. If first row was "1" it gets moved down. if last row was "1" we wanted to mark the next row which doesn't exist. Just my two cents.